# Creating a dll from classes in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, dll

I have a few classes with the same namespace, and I want to put all of them in a dll file, and use it in other places.

I read the guide on Microsoft's website:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3707x96z(v=vs.80).aspx

They suggested this:

> To build the file [myDllName].DLL, compile the two files [myClass1].cs and
> [myClass2].cs using the following command line:
>
> csc /target:library /out:[myDllName].DLL [myClass1].cs [myClass2].cs

I wrote it in a cmd window and got an error that there is no such command as csc.
Plus, how it will find my files without a path?

**So what is the right way of doing it? Where should I write it?**

I saw some posts here with Library classes.. but not sure how it can help me.
My classes are in a different solution, and I just want to use it as an external dll, and not within the same solution.
In this case, Microsoft's guide seems perfect, if it will work.

Comment: Is your question _"How do I compile from the commandline?"_, or _"How to compile code and create an assembly?"_, as the latter is a bit easier to do from Visual Studio itself.

Comment: No no.. I know how to make a dll from a Class Library for example (just build it), I want to know how to put a few classes in a dll, and then use this dll in a different solution

Comment: The easiest way to do that, not for now but especially when maintenance kicks in (change one line of code, add / remove a class, you will have to recompile), is to just create a new Class Library and add the relevant classes to it. Then everyone on your team or whatever can open the project and rebuild it, and you can as well reference a project as a DLL. If you do insist on compiling it yourself from the command line, please familiarize yourself with how the command line and paths work, as that is the only thing stopping you from it now.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Visual Studio Command Prompt window, all the necessary environment variables are set for you. In Windows 7, you can access that window from the Start menu by opening the Microsoft Visual Studio Version\Visual Studio Tools folder. In Windows 8, the Visual Studio Command Prompt is called the Developer Command Prompt for VS2012, and you can find it by searching from the Start screen.

[source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/78f4aasd.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just create a separate 'Class Library' project in your solution in Visual Studio?

You can than easily add it as a project reference to all other projects that need it.

You can create Solution Folders in VS to logically group projects.

Comment: I thought it is "cleaner" to make it outside, no?

Comment: Not if you don't define "cleaner". Just add a Class Library project and reference it.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have 4 projects (class libraries) in the solution, and each one of them have some meaning (not sure how to explain..) they represent stuff.. And the dll I want to create now, is just a helper to one of them... So it shouldn't be on the same level as the main 4.. You know what I mean?

Comment: Crystal clear, but I don't agree. Compiling from the commandline is not a substitute to creating a project. If one project in your solution requires this functionality, why shouldn't it be _in_ your solution? _Why_ do you want a non-reproducable DLL floating around? (Unless you save the build command, which almost is equal to creating a project file, apart from the benefits you miss from not doing so).

Comment: Makes sense. So now a design question. Where will be a good place to put it? besides creating another project, that may be a bit confusing in the middle of the main 4? Maybe I should just put the classes inside their "Parent" project that is using them?

Comment: @user990635 - I've suggested a solution folder for grouping your projects.

Comment: You mean adding a folder inside the relevant project and drop the classes there?

Comment: @user990635 - You can organize the files the way you want. The generally accepted rule is for a folder structure to match the namespaces.

Comment: You could perhaps add a Solution Folder.

Comment: @CodeCaster - have you actually read my answer and comments above? ;-)

Comment: @Jakub OP did not seem to get the **Solution** part of [Solution Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haytww03(v=vs.100).aspx). :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can run the vsvars batch file from a command prompt and it will set paths for you, for that instance of `cmd.exe`
Mine is here:

```
>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure csc.exe is in your PATH environment variable.

You should have a vsvars32.bat that was installed with Visual Studio. You can run that to automatically add it to the path, or dig down in regedit to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP
```

Look through the subtrees in there for your framework version, and for an InstallPath key. That should tell you what directory to look in.

You can then use that, and:

```
WHERE /r "the_directory_you_found" csc.exe
```

to find the path. Add that to your system environment variables, and you should be able to find it.

As for the path of the class files, either run the command from the directory they're in, or specify the path when specifying the class files.

Comment: Can you give me more details?

Comment: Working on it, just a sec.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Visual Studio installed, you could try creating a 'Class Library' project; Or you can run csc.exe by Launching "Visual Studio Command Prompt".

If you don't have Visual Studio installed but have .net framework installed. You can run csc.exe from the framework installation directory.

Installation directory path for .net Framework 4.0 :

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319